# webstorm code highlighting and code completion for meteor packages

Tags: webstorm, code-completion, codehighlighter

I have configured meteor on webstorm and I can see code highlighting and code completion for meteor, but when I add new packages (for example: aldeed:collection2), code highlighting and code completion doesnt work for new packages. How can I make sure that code highlighting and completion also work for new and installed packages.
Regards, Chidan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open '.meteor/packages' file and run '**Import packages as library**' action (the action will be shown)
[image]

Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17503

Comment: Hi, sorry for naive question, where or in which tool should I open  '.meteor/packages'? and in webstorm where do I find option for 'Import packages as library' ?

Comment: @ChiduMurthy I have attached screenshot for you